# how to make public key pressed event in java

Tags: java

I had created an application using net-beans.added some text fields.I need to make common key pressed event for text fields.I am beginner how can i handle this.first field is "EMPID" and Second Field Is "NAME".this is what I want.whenever I press Enter key i need to transfer focus to another field.this is what i wrote.

```
private void EMPIDKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
       int Lastkey=evt.getKeyCode();
        if (Lastkey==10)
           EMPID.transferFocus();
    }
```

this is what I want to do whenever I press enter key I need to transfer focus from current field to another. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead EMPID.transferFocus() you need : NAME.requestFocus()